# How to makes csrf token as one time use

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

Using .Net core Api to generate csrf token and validating token using middle ware concept,but once validated the csrf token it's should not be reusable but if we are sending old token in headers it's still validating successful

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If a token has been created ,you could not let it expire manually,try to set the deadline as short as possible